# Set cookie to a div that is shown after few second of video play?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I have a div element that shows up after 20 second of video play.If you will play the video after 20 second of play a div will shows up. Now I want  to set cookie so that if the div have been  shown once ,it keeps on showing unless the user clear the cache (**cookie logic**).

```
This is what I have tried so far -
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9L29o365/

How can  this be achieved?

Thanks In Advance .

Comment: try read up on https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/ , it should be fairly simple to make it

Comment: Take a look at [How do I create and read a value from cookie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)  and with jquery [How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-do-i-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen ok let me check that

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef ok let me try :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code**

set cookie

```
Cookies.set('div-20sec', 'visited');
```

get cookie

```
var val=Cookies.get('div-20sec');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9L29o365/2/)

Comment: Perfect Answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could set the cookie in your `onPlayProgress` function, and read the same cookie handle in your click play listener:

```
// set 
document.cookie='20secSet=true';
// get
var cookieVal =  document.cookie
                         .split(',')
                         .indexOf('20secSet=true');
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/9L29o365/3/) an example using your code.

Comment: ok I am new to cookie method.. can you explain how it works.. and also I see the red div hidden everytime I loads.. even if I had played it once

Comment: You can find sufficient documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie). The principle is setting the value in the cookie bag, then having to parse out the value you are interested in later.  There are additional options related to expiry.

Comment: Can you describe how you are not able to produce the red box after playing the video for 20 seconds?

Comment: I am able to produce the red box.. Not able able to retain it when iI reload the page.